# How to make jquery hover event fire repeatedly

Tags: jquery, hover, infinite-carousel

I have a infinite carousel that I want to move when I hover over the next and previous buttons. Right now hover only fires this once. I want the carousel to continue moving while the mouse is within the next or previous buttons.

Any Suggestions?

```
jQuery.fn.carousel = function(previous, next, options){
 var sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];

 if (sliderList) {
  var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true"),
  elmnts = jQuery(sliderList).children(),
  numElmts = elmnts.length,
  sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
  shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
  firstElementOnViewPort = 1,
  isAnimating = false;

  for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
   jQuery(sliderList).css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px");
   jQuery(sliderList).append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
  }

  jQuery(previous).hover(function(event){
   if (!isAnimating) {
    if (firstElementOnViewPort == 1) {
     jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "-" + numElmts * sizeFirstElmnt + "px");
     firstElementOnViewPort = numElmts;
    }
    else {
     firstElementOnViewPort--;
    }

    jQuery(sliderList).animate({
     left: "+=" + increment,
     y: 0,
     queue: true
    }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
    isAnimating = true;
   }

  });

  jQuery(next).hover(function(event){
   if (!isAnimating) {
    if (firstElementOnViewPort > numElmts) {
     firstElementOnViewPort = 2;
     jQuery(sliderList).css('left', "0px");
    }
    else {
     firstElementOnViewPort++;
    }
    jQuery(sliderList).animate({
     left: "-=" + increment,
     y: 0,
     queue: true
    }, "swing", function(){isAnimating = false;});
    isAnimating = true;
   }
  });


 }
};
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the isAnimating = true; line?

Answer (score 2):

As for triggering events, see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('#idOfElement').trigger('mouseover'); // or similar
```

In the case of your plugin, you'll want to capture mouseOut as well. If at the end of your animation, check to see if mouseOut was fired and if not - fire another hover.

For your code, i would refactor it a bit:

```
(function($){  
jQuery.fn.carousel = function(previousButton, nextButton, options){
 var $sliderList = jQuery(this).children()[0];
 var $previous = $(previousButton);
 var $next = $(nextButton);
 var isAnimating = false;
 var buttonPressed = false;

 function previous(obj) {
   buttonPressed = true;
   // previous animation code
   // when you're done animating, see if buttonPressed is true still (if out was fired, then it's false)
  // if true - call previous again
 }
 function next(obj) {
   buttonPressed = true;
   // next animation code
 }
 function out() {
   buttonPressed = false;
 }

 if (sliderList) {
    var increment = jQuery(sliderList).children().outerWidth("true"),
        elmnts = $sliderList.children(),
        numElmts = elmnts.length,
        sizeFirstElmnt = increment,
        shownInViewport = Math.round(jQuery(this).width() / sizeFirstElmnt),
        firstElementOnViewPort = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < shownInViewport; i++) {
      $sliderList.css('width',(numElmts+shownInViewport)*increment + increment + "px"); // use the cached sliderList, ya?
      $sliderList.append(jQuery(elmnts[i]).clone());
    }

    $previous.hover(previous, out);
    $next.hover(next, out); // calls next on over, out on exit

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out and for responding so quickly. I am still a rookie with this stuff and am still having trouble. If you could give me more detailed help (like your talking to a 5 year old) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: hope that helps ( see new answer )

Comment: I think you meant to say false in `out()` -- function out() { buttonPressed = false; }